# Can I copy a cross compiler tool chain between systems (I did before)?

Tags: ubuntu

I tested fairly extensively with Ubuntu 10.04 Beta 2 Server in a VM, and was able to simply copy (read  `tar x`) a cross compiled tool chain from an Ubuntu 8.10 VM.  I created the tar myself, which is essentially a lot of stuff in `\usr\local`.

Now that I've got a bare metal installation of Ubuntu 10.04 proper, the copy isn't working.  In particularly, I'm getting the error:

```
$ arm-linux-gcc
-bash: /usr/local/bin/arm-linux-gcc: No such file or directory
```

I've got the systems side by side in SSH windows ... any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu Beta shipped with 32 bit libraries installed, so this fixed it:

```
 sudo apt-get install linux32 ia32*
```

Which may have been overkill, but it got the job done.

Answer was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924566/can-i-copy-a-cross-compiler-tool-chain-between-systems-i-did-before/2924589#2924589).

Answer (score 1):

The file /usr/local/bin/arm-linux-gcc exists ? Is it the same plateform than your old (32bits/64bits) ?

Comment: err, yes it does exist.  How would explain the verbosity of the error?   And no it's not the same platform, as stated, the first two were VM's and the final was a bare metal install.  The confusing bit was the one VM was 32 and the other was 64.

Comment: The message is not really clear, but it happens when your software is in 32 bits on a 64 bits machine without 32bits libraries installed, as you find in the other post.